# How can I tell a (Android) WebView to start off at a custom scale?

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to tell a `WebView` to scale the page down to a certain percent. I've tried using [setInitialScale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale%28int%29) as that seems to be exactly what I want, but it seemed to have no effect.

Am I just missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Android are you running?: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5143

Comment: I've tried it on 1.6 and 2.1 on a G1, Droid, and the emulator.

Comment: is everything else running correctly? i mean, is it displaying what you want, when you want, but just at the wrong scale?

Comment: Yep... everything looks great, just a little larger than I'd like.

Comment: Basically I just want to tell it to scale to 95% instead of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the full code available, nor do i have eclipse at the moment but I remember you start with something like this:

```
final View zoom = mWebView.getZoomControls ( );
mContentView.addView ( zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS );
zoom.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
```

then you should be able to set the zoom.

You set the zoom by doing the following:

```
mWebView.getSettings ( ).setSupportZoom ( true );
mWebView.setInitialScale ( 25 );
```